# how to call a function with Combobox tkinter after selecting the element needed

Tags: tkinter

i want to call a function that after selection one of the materials it gets me the value of it' eletrical resistance and after that i want to use it in calculation

```
def selected():
    if tow1.get() == "Cu":
        Er=0.8
        print(Er)
    elif tow1.get() == CuSn:
        Er=..
    elif tow1.get() == .:
        Er=...
    else:
        Er=..

data1 = ("Cu", "CuSn", "CuMg", "Al")
tow1 = Combobox(frame31, values=data1)
tow1.current(0)
tow1.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the `<<ComboboxSelected>>` event. The bound function will receive an object that represents the event, so you'll need to modify your `selected` function slightly:

```
def selected(event):
    value = event.widget.get()
    print("value: '{}'".format(value))
...
tow1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", selected)
```